# upload images or videos to remote server using phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am doing project in android phonegap.Here I want to upload images and videos to remote server.
I used the following link.
http://zacvineyard.com/blog/2011/03/upload-a-file-to-a-remote-server-with-phonegap

I also change some options like options.chunkedMode = false ,android:debuggable="true" and 
. But still it shows error code 3.I am using the **cordova-2.0.0.js** version.Can anyone suggest some answer.

My js code is

```
    **

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            // PhoneGap is ready
    function onDeviceReady() {
      // Do cool things here...
            }

    function getImage() {

                // Retrieve image file location from specified source
                navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
                alert('get picture failed');
                },
                {quality: 50,
                destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
                }
                );
    }

    function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {

                var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                options.fileKey="file";
                options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

                var params = new Object();
                params.value1 = "test";
                params.value2 = "param";

                options.params = params;
                options.chunkedMode = false;

                var ft = new FileTransfer();
                ft.upload(imageURI, "url of ther server/upload.php", win, fail, options, true);
                console.log("H");
    }

    function win(r) {
                console.log("HIIIIIiiii");
                console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
                console.log("Response = " + r.response);
                console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
                alert(r.response);
    }

    function fail(error) {
                alert("There is something");
                alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    }

    </script>
```

**

and my php code is

```
<?php

print_r($_FILES);
$new_image_name = "namethisimage.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/".$new_image_name);

?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: show some code of your upload

Comment: Does it capture the camera image correctly?

Comment: @IanDevlin Yes.It capture the camera image correctly.When i press the upload button, it shows the error code 3 after sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the URL in question to your whitelist?

e.g. in config.xml do you have something like:

```
<access origin="www.myurl.com" subdomains="true" />
```

or

```
<access origin="*" />
```

which allows all URLs.

Error code 3 is a FileTransferError.CONNECTION_ERR by the way.

Comment: I have added <access origin=".*"/> in the config.xml

Comment: Try removing the . that's before the * perhaps?

Comment: Ian Devlin I tried by removing (.) before *. still same error.

Comment: Hmmm, odd. Since it is a communication error, it generally means that it doesn't have access to the server that you are trying to upload the file to. Can you verify that it can access that server, even if it's simply to open a link on it?

Comment: I can access the server.I can access the database using the php file inside the same server using ajax request.

Comment: Make sure the URL you are using does not refer to localhost (127.0.0.1) as on the device that means it would refer to itself and not your webserver running PHP.

Comment: @SimonMacDonald Problem was with my wifi connection.Thanks for your answer.

Comment: That sounds odd, since otherwise you wouldn't have been able to connect to the server at all, which you answered above that you could do. Oh well, glad you sorted it.

Comment: @IanDevlin I connected to the server using my desktop.Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Ah ok I see, I should have been more explicit in what I asked then as I meant from the device. Ah well :-)